# Using Stored Procedure to check Value has attribute or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Can someone show me how to check value has attribute before set parameter and get data?

This is my XML:

```
<Setup>
  <Include Type="Product">
    <Value uomid="8078">468908_3:9500;2:10000;</Value>
    <Value>468906_3:9500;2:10000;</Value>
  </Include>  
</Setup>
```

This is my stored procedure to get data

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
            SELECT  YS_PromotionID,
                    PromotionName,
                    PromotionDescription,
                    PromotionSetup,
                    IsActive,
                    FromDate,
                    ToDate,
                    ShowWhenUsed,
                    SortOrder,
                    dbo.YS_GetLoyaltyProgramNameInPromotion('+CAST(@accountID AS VARCHAR)+',PromotionSetup) as LoaiThanhVien,
                    (PromotionSetup.query(''
                                for $PS in Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Product'''']/Value[@uomid='''''+CAST(@uomID as nvarchar)+'''''][text()]                                        
                                   where contains($PS, ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '_'''') or $PS = ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '''''
                                   return data($PS)      
                        '')).value(''(.)'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as InfoProductPromotion
            FROM    YS_Promotion
            WHERE   YS_AccountID = ' + CAST(@accountID AS NVARCHAR) + ' AND
                    (''' + CAST(@checkAll AS NVARCHAR) + ''' = 1 OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) >= CONVERT(DATE, FromDate) ) AND
                    (''' + CAST(@checkAll AS NVARCHAR) + ''' = 1 OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) <= CONVERT(DATE, ToDate) ) AND
                    (''' + CAST(@checkAll AS NVARCHAR) + ''' = 1 OR IsActive = 1) AND                       
                    (''' + CAST(@branchID AS NVARCHAR) + ''' = 0 OR ((PromotionSetup.exist(''Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Branch'''']/Value[text() = ''''' + CAST(@branchID AS NVARCHAR) + ''''']'') = 1 or PromotionSetup.exist(''Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Branch'''']/Value[text() = ''''0'''']'') = 1))) AND
                    ('''+CAST(@applyForAllCustomer AS varchar) +''' = ''1'' or dbo.YS_fcCheckPromotionApplyForCustomerLoyalty(YS_PromotionID) = 0)
        ) AS Temp WHERE InfoProductPromotion <> ''''
        --) AS Temp WHERE InfoProductPromotion <> '''' or (''' + CAST(@checkAll AS NVARCHAR) + ''' <> 1 AND PromotionSetup.exist(''Setup/Include[@Type = ''''ALLProduct'''']/Value[text() = ''''1'''']'') = 1 )
             order by ' + @sortExpression
```

Based on my XML file, I have 2 values, 1 is have an attribute is uomid and another one is not.

My problem is here:

First of all, I want to set `@productID` and get value. Before I select `Value` attribute with parameter `@uomid`, I want to check that value has attribute or not, after that I will set 2 parameters in `PromotionSetup.query` to get data.

Can someone help me to edit store procedure to complete it?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: i'm looking for method how to resolved my problems

Comment: I'd be good to learn to narrow the question as much as possible. Try to remove all unnecessary things from your qustion.